# emacs using sort-regexp-fields to sort lines

Tags: sorting, emacs

How could I use the `sort-regexp-fields` to emulate the sort-numeric-fields. I tried like this:

```
123
345
90
80
1999
```

`M-x` `sort-regexp-fields`

`Regexp specifying records to sort:` \ ([0-9]+\)

`Regexp specifying key within record:` \, \#1

But it can’t work.
what I really want to sort is something like this:

```
foo index: 123
index: 345 boo
…
```

the question is: I want to sort the lines by the number after the word “index”, but the number is not in the same field, they just have a word “index” before it. what should I do to complete this? anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort-regexp-fields` doesn't do lexicographical compare, and there's no trivial way to get it to do that.  That said, we can use a trick of defining our own command, and using that command to signal to some advice to shoe-horn in a lexicographical compare.

The following command does what you want, provided you mark the region around the lines you want to compare:

```
(defun my-line-sort (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (sort-regexp-fields nil "^.*: +\\([0-9]+\\).*$" "\\1" begin end))

(defun compare-buffer-substrings-lexigraphically (b1 b2)
  (< (string-to-number (buffer-substring-no-properties (car b1) (cdr b1)))
     (string-to-number (buffer-substring-no-properties (car b2) (cdr b2)))))

(defadvice sort-subr (before sort-subr-lexical-compare activate)
  "In special case, force predicate to be a lexical compare"
  (when (eq this-command 'my-line-sort)
    (ad-set-arg 5 'compare-buffer-substrings-lexigraphically)))
```

Comment: thanks for replay, but I tried both of the two method, nothing happened with the input data.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think your answer addresses the (part of the) question about numeric vs lexicographic sorting order.

Comment: Whoa, that is fine art! I just learned about `ad-set-arg`, thanks. It's a bit disappointing that there is no standard way to provide a custom sort function to `sort-regexp-field` and friends.

Comment: @TreyJackson sorry for my poor understanding of the regex, it seems not work with my example:
123
345
90
80
1999
can you explain the `sort-regexp-fields nil "^.*: +\\([0-9]+\\).*$" "\\1" begin end` to me? what I am doing is as following: first `C-x C-e` to the three expressions, second choose the five line of numbers as a marked region. then `M-x` and `my-line-sort`, to my poor understanding, nothing happened to the marked region. is there anything wrong with my operations?

Comment: @TreyJackson I just changed the expression `sort-regexp-fields nil "^.*: +\\([0-9]+\\).*$" "\\1" begin end` to `sort-regexp-fields nil "^.*\\([0-9]+\\).*$" "\\1" begin end`, it works to the input data: 123 345 90 80 1999, each number at the begin of the line, but the result is `90
80
123
345
1999` is there something wrong?

Comment: @TreyJackson I understand that the `: +` is used to match the `index`: `123` your answer is right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, this will do what you want:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`sort-regexp-fields`<kbd>RET</kbd>`index: \([0-9]+\)`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\1`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: I tried this way, it only sort the top digit of the number, for example:`2` `129` `32` will be sorted (using the method you mentioned)  to `129` `2` `32`, note the top digit of the number is sorted. sorry for the poor English.